# CSS delays in changing the visibility of an element from `visible` to `hidden`

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navbar that contains three elements. Horizontally, from left-to-right, they are: `socialMediaIcons`, `logoArea`, and `navBarOptionsList`.

I wrote javascript and CSS such that, when the user begins to scroll down the page, the `socialMediaIcons` and `navBarOptionsList`'s visibility change to `hidden`.

The problem is, the `socialMediaIcons` element lags by about half a second to become hidden after the user scrolls down. The `navBarOptionsList` hides immediately after even slightly scrolling down the page (this is the expected behaviour -- and it is what I'd like the `socialMediaIcons` to do too).

Below is the CSS (which is where I suspect the problem is), as well as the Javascript (detailing the logic for hiding the two elements) and HTML:

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS, and stupid fontawesome shyt -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

        <!-- Required CDNs: jQuery, Popper.js, Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!--Favicon-->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../resources/codigoinitiativefavi.ico"/>

        <!--Custom CSS Stylesheet-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css"/>
        <title>Codigo Initiative</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <nav class="navBar">

            <div class="socialMediaNavBarArea">
                <ul class="socialMediaIconList">
                    <li class="socialMediaIcon"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li>
                    <li class="socialMediaIcon"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li>
                    <li class="socialMediaIcon"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></li>
                    <li class="socialMediaIcon"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></li>
                    <li class="socialMediaIcon"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="logoArea">
                <img id="navBarLogocaster" src="../resources/codigoinitiativewhite.png" alt="Codigo Initiative">
            </div>

            <!--TODO: Nav bar options list font style should match the Codigo Initiative logo font style-->
            <div class="navBarOptionsAreaFullScreen">
              <ul class="navbarOptionsList">
                  <li class="navItem">
                      <a class="navLink" href="">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="navItem">
                      <a class="navLink" href="">Resources</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="navItem">
                      <a class="navLink" href="">Curriculums</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="navItem">
                    <a class="navLink" href="">Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="hamIconNavOptions">
                <ul class="hamIconNavOptionsList">
                    <li class="hamburgerIconNavOptions"><a href="#" onClick="toggleHamburgerNavOptionsList()">&#9776;</a>
                        <ul id="hamburgerIconNavOptionsNestedList">
                            <li class="hamburgerIconNavOptionsNestedListItem"><a class="navOptionAnchorItem" href="">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="hamburgerIconNavOptionsNestedListItem"><a class="navOptionAnchorItem" href="">Resources</a></li>
                            <li class="hamburgerIconNavOptionsNestedListItem"><a class="navOptionAnchorItem" href="">Curriculums</a></li>
                            <li class="hamburgerIconNavOptionsNestedListItem"><a class="navOptionAnchorItem" href="">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="placeholder"></div>

    </body>

    <footer>    
        <script src="../index.js"></script>
    </footer>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
/*Hamburger Icon styling*/

.hamburgerIconNavOptions{
    color: white;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

/*Styling for the hamburger icon (which is really a list)*/
.hamIconNavOptionsList{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none; /*removing the bullet point*/
}

/*styling the nested list in the hamburger icon*/
#hamburgerIconNavOptionsNestedList{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none; /*Removiing the bullet points*/
    background-color: #13204f;
    opacity: .5; /*Making this bad boy transparent. (0 is completely transperent, 9 is solid black)*/
}

/*Removing the default underlining provided by the anchor tag's default styling*/
.navOptionAnchorItem{
    text-decoration: none; /*Removing the default styling from the anchor element*/
    color: white;
}

/*Removing the underlining of links provided by the anchor tag's default styling*/
.navOptionAnchorItem:link { 
    text-decoration: none; 
} 

/*Removing the underlining that occurs by default on anchor tags when hovering over them.*/
.navOptionAnchorItem:hover { 
    text-decoration: none; 
}

/*Styling each list item within the hamburger icon's nested list*/
.hamburgerIconNavOptions{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
}

@media(max-width: 1200px) {
    /*This logic will execute when the screen's width becomes too small to display everything*/
    .socialMediaIconList{
        display: none; /*Will hide the list items when the screen's width is too small to display them*/
    }

    .socialMediaIconList.toggleCls{
        display: none; /*will remove the social media icon list if the screen isn't wide enough to display it*/
    }

    .hamburgerIconSocialMedia {
        display: none; /*TODO: Don't really need a hamburger bar to begin with. Need to come back and remove this.*/
    }

    /*Same stuff as above, except for the navBar options list*/
    .navbarOptionsList{
        display: none;
    }

    #hamburgerIconNavOptionsNestedList.toggleCls{
        display: block;
    }

    /*The screen is too small. But hide the nested list that belons to the hamburger icon. Will be displayed when the hamburger icon is clicked.*/
    #hamburgerIconNavOptionsNestedList{
        display: none;
    }
}

/*Make the hamburger icon disappear when the screen is large enough to display all list view items*/
@media(min-width: 1199px) {
    .hamIconNavOptions{
        display: none; /*Hides the hamburger icon when the screen is large enough to display everything*/
    }

    .socialMediaIconList{
        display: initial; /*Shows the social media links*/
    }

    .navbarOptionsList{
        display: initial;
    }
}

.navBar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; /*Aligns items horizontally*/
    flex-wrap: nowrap; /*Prevents overflow wrapping. We'd rather everything get packed on a single row.*/
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #13204f;
    height: 125px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.socialMediaNavBarArea {
    position: relative; 
    width: 25%;
    padding: 30px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.logoArea {
    position: relative; 
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

.navBarOptionsAreaFullScreen {
    position: relative; 
    width: 30%;
    padding: 30px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

/*Social Media area*/
 .socialMediaIcon {
    list-style: none;
    margin: auto; 
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: .5s;
}

.socialMediaIconList {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 90px;
}

.socialMediaNavBarIcons {
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-53%, -50%);
    position: absolute;  
}

.socialMediaIcon:hover {
    color: #565759;
    border: 1px solid #565759;
    transition: .75s;
} 

/*Navigation Bar logo area*/
#navBarLogocaster {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 75%;

    /*Aligns the image center horizontal and vertical*/
    position: absolute;  
    top: 0;  
    bottom: 0;  
    left: 0;  
    right: 0;  
    margin: auto;
}

/*Navigation Bar options area*/
.navItem {
    display: inline;
}

.placeholder {
    height: 5000px;
}

.navLink {
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
}

.navLink:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #565759;
    transition: .75s;
}
```

Javascript:

```js
/**
 * The following logic controls what will happen when the user scrolls down on the screen.
 * The navbar will decrease in heigh slightly.
*/
window.onscroll = function() {configureNavBar()};

function configureNavBar() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
        //The user is scrolling down, so minimize the nav bar, and hide all corollary navbar items to reduce clutter.
        document.querySelector(".navBar").style.height = "90px";
        hideSocialMediaIcons();
        hideNavBarOptions();
  } else {
        //The user has scrolled back up to the top. Display all corollary navbar options/details.
        document.querySelector(".navBar").style.height = "120px";
        unhideSocialMediaIcons();
        unhideNavBarOptions();
  }

}

/**
 * Will hide the social media icons (if it is even being displayed at all)
 */
function hideSocialMediaIcons() {
    let socialMediaIconList = document.querySelector(".socialMediaIconList");

    //If the social media icons are being displayed, hide them.
    if(socialMediaIconList.style.visibility != "hidden") {
        socialMediaIconList.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        //no further action needed, as the social media icons are already hidden.
    }
}

/**
 * Will hide the navbar's (full-screen) options when scrolling down.
 */
function hideNavBarOptions(){
    let navBarOptions = document.querySelector(".navbarOptionsList");

    //If the social media icons are being displayed, hide them.
    if(navBarOptions.style.visibility != "hidden") {
        navBarOptions.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        //no further action needed, as the social media icons are already hidden.
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put this in a codesandbox or codepen and share the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is transition duration set for `socialMediaIcon` class but for `.navBarOptionsList` no duration set.